# Automatically discard windows msg error dialog when app started by my program crashes (Win7-32, C++, VSE2013)

Tags: c++, windows-7

I am writing a small utility to monitor and relaunch other console app (with known and constant .exe name and path) under Windows 7 32bit. I use C++ and MS VS Express 2013.
The problem is there is a possability, that upon restart the monitored application could crash producing error dialog about crash details. My utility is intended to keep restarting the application every 1-2min interval until it runs successufully (yes I know this is not a good thing, but I have no access to the original app source so I have to implement such a "patch").
So my question is - how to disable/auto close such a dialog box generated by  other app on the machine in the most efficient way?
Also any tip on developing such kind of apps is very much appriciated.

EDIT Thanks for the answers, so far settled with the following code:

```
while (true)        
{
    //Check if output file of controller_id_780M.exe is updating
    if (!controller_id_780M_OUTPUT_OK)
    {
        std::system("taskkill /F /T /IM controller_id_780M.exe");
        std::system("taskkill /F /T /IM WerFault.exe");
        ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), TEXT("controller_id_780M.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    }
    Sleep(100000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before launching the other process, call `SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)`. This suppresses the crash dialog. The error mode is inherited by child processes, so the child processes will not show crash dialogs.

Comment: Is it possible that the child process is explicitly re-enabling crash dialogs? Another option is [`WerAddExcludedApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513617(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows function `EnumWindowsProc` to find error window, try use in `EnumWindowsProc` function loop: `GetWindowText` and `GetClassName` it should contain string like "error", "warning". Then you have this window HANDLE, so you can send proper message to that window.